# Add multiple value to a query variable in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the below code in functions.php to add custom query variables to my WordPress project.

```
<?php
function add_custom_query_var( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "brand";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );
?>
```

And then on the content page I am using:

```
<?php echo $currentbrand = get_query_var('brand'); ?>
```

So now I can pass a URL like:

http://myexamplesite.com/store/?brand=nike

and get nike in result.

How can I pass multiple values for a brand. So I would like to have 3 values for brand say, nike, adidas and woodland.

I have tried the following and none of them works:

1. http://myexamplesite.com/store/?brand=nike&brand=adidas&brand=woodland
   It just returns the last brand, in this case woodland.
2. http://myexamplesite.com/store/?brand=nike+adidas+woodland
   This returns all three with spaces. I kind of think this is not the correct solution. So may be there is a correct way to pass multiple values for a query variable and retrieve them in an array may be so that a loop can be run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass query parameters in this way;

brand1=nike&brand2=adidas&brand3=woodland

So, different key for each brand

On the page, recieving values

```
$params = $_GET;
$brands = array();
foreach($params as $k=>$v) {
    if(substr($k,0,5)=="brand") {
        $brands[] = $v;
    }
}
```

**Alternatively**

Using your 2nd method
http://myexamplesite.com/store/?brand=nike+adidas+woodland

```
$brands = explode(" ", $_GET['brand']);
```

Alternative method looks easier

Comment: Thanks. Different key will work. But I would like to know if it is possible with just a single key.

Comment: @KiranDash updated the answer, I guess alternative method is what you looking for

Comment: I guess I will go with this. But what I was really looking for here was if WordPress has a built in solution for this. Which I guess does not exist

Answer (score 3):

Usually you would pass the parameter like `?brand[]=unresponsibleCompany1&brand[]=otherBrandThatDoesNotCareMuch&brand[]=bunchOfCriminals` .

In your WordPress PHP code, then `get_query_var( 'brand' )` will return you an Array.

Everything else sounds like a relatively cheap but costy workaround.

Comment: Surprisingly, this worked perfectly! Thank you very much for the heads-up.